# Installing pip on Suse 11 with Python 2.6.9

Tags: python, pip, sles

I am looking to install pip on my Linux sevrer with Suse 11 and has Python 2.6.9. I tried with zypper install python-pip but I got the below error

```
zypper install python-pip

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Package 'python-pip' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Am I missing anything here , is there any other method to download pip ?

Comment: Did you try to refresh the repository before? sudo zypper ref

Answer (score 1):

You can install pip using [python code](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

To install pip, securely download get-pip.py:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

As when running any script downloaded from the web, ensure that you have reviewed the code and are happy that it works as you expect. Then run the following:

```
python get-pip.py
```